# MSFlexGrid Edit VB6

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

Currently I am working on vb6 application. I want to show data in MSFlexgrid But there is no edit Facility in MSFlexgrid Control.

Is there Any way to Edit MSFlexgrid?

Comment: The old VB5-carryover MSFlexGrid and the improved VB6 MSHFlexgrid are both "display" controls that do not provide any user data input or editing facility.  You'd either have to write the code to "float" a marquee TextBox over cells as they're "edited" or else move to the old DBGrid or newer DataGrid control instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way using hidden Textbox. On the double click on the cell the textbox will be visible and Edit is possible here is code snippet check it

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   'Setting Col And row

    MSFlexGrid1.Cols = 3
    MSFlexGrid1.Rows = 10
    'First row
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(0, 0) = "ID"
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(0, 1) = "Date"
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(0, 2) = "Voucher Type"
    'some data
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(1, 0) = "E0000001"
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(2, 0) = "E0000001"
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(1, 1) = "01/04/10"
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(2, 1) = "01/04/10"    
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(1, 2) = "Jrnl"
    MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(2, 2) = "Jrnl"
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_DblClick()

    'If MSFlexGrid1.Col = 3 Or MSFlexGrid1.Col = 6 Or MSFlexGrid1.Col = 7 Then
        GridEdit Asc(" ")
    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

        GridEdit KeyAscii

End Sub

Sub GridEdit(KeyAscii As Integer)

  'use correct font  
  Text1.FontName = MSFlexGrid1.FontName
  Text1.FontSize = MSFlexGrid1.FontSize

  Select Case KeyAscii

     Case 0 To Asc(" ")
        Text1 = MSFlexGrid1
        Text1.text = Trim(Text1.text)
        Text1.SelStart = 1000

     Case Else
         Text1 = MSFlexGrid1
         Text1.text = Trim(Text1.text)
        Text1.SelStart = 1000

 End Select

  'position the edit box


  Text1.Left = MSFlexGrid1.CellLeft + MSFlexGrid1.Left

  Text1.Top = MSFlexGrid1.CellTop + MSFlexGrid1.Top

  Text1.Width = MSFlexGrid1.CellWidth

  Text1.Height = MSFlexGrid1.CellHeight

  Text1.Visible = True

  Text1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_LeaveCell()

  If Text1.Visible Then

    If MSFlexGrid1.Col = 6 Or MSFlexGrid1.Col = 7 Then
        If Text1.text = "" Then
            Text1.text = " "
        End If
    End If
     MSFlexGrid1 = Text1
     Text1.Visible = False

  End If

End Sub

Private Sub MSFlexGrid1_GotFocus()

  If Text1.Visible Then

    If MSFlexGrid1.Col = 6 Or MSFlexGrid1.Col = 7 Then

        If Text1.text = "" Then
            Text1.text = " "
        End If

    End If

     MSFlexGrid1 = Text1.text
     Text1.Visible = False

  End If

End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

  'noise suppression

  If MSFlexGrid1.Col <> 6 And MSFlexGrid1.Col <> 7 Then

    KeyAscii = 0

  End If

  If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then

    KeyAscii = 0

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this take care of tabbing on the form?

Comment: I have stopped all the TabStop excluding MSFlexgrid and i have write a code What i want on tab Key.

Comment: I added `Call MSFlexGrid1_LeaveCell` in the second If block of `Text1_KeyPress` so the edit mode is left on pressing the return key. Did the same in `Text1_LostFocus`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you also try below code. This doesnt require text box.

```
'Put this code in MSFlexGrid Keypress Event

'===================================================
Private Sub MSFlexGrid_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
With MSFlexGrid
    Select Case KeyAscii

        Case 8: 'IF KEY IS BACKSPACE THEN
            If .Text <> "" Then .Text = _
             Left$(.Text, (Len(.Text) - 1))
        Case 13: 'IF KEY IS ENTER THEN
            Select Case .Col
                Case Is < (.Cols - 1):
                    SendKeys "{right}"
                Case (.Cols - 1):
                    If (.Row + 1) = .Rows Then
                        .Rows = .Rows + 1
                    End If
                    SendKeys "{home}" + "{down}"
            End Select
        Case Else
            .Text = .Text + Chr$(KeyAscii)
            'write your own keyascii Validations under 
                   'commented lines
            Select Case .Col
                Case 0, 1, 2:
                    'if (your condition(s)) then
                        'accept only charectors
                    'Else
                    '   keyascii=0
                    'End If
                Case Else:
            End Select
    End Select
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for putting code in incorrect way. Will take care next time

Comment: IF Someone who Want to navigate cursor with up arrow keys than it will not work.

Comment: Would be nice if you could somehow show which cell has focus.